# How Do We Set id For Data That Showed With Volley Json Array Request

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I have some problem about setting and getting id from data that showed with volley JSon array request.

I've tried to do this, but it fail.

**ChildTidur.java**

```
public class ChildTidur extends AppCompatActivity implements TidurAdapter.ContactsAdapterListener {
    private static final String TAG = ChildTidur.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Story> storyList;
    private TidurAdapter mAdapter;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private TextView noFavtsTV;
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";

    // url to fetch contacts json
    private static final String URL = "https://api.kafeinkode.com/childtidur.json";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.child_tidur);

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

        SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh = findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
        pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        //toolbar logo and desc
        Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTidur);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar); //munculkan menu ke toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //this line shows back button

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noFavtsTV = findViewById(R.id.no_favt_text);
        storyList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new TidurAdapter(this, storyList, this, appPreferences);

        // white background notification bar
        whiteNotificationBar(recyclerView);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new TidurDekor(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL, 36));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //Make call to AsyncTask
        new AsyncLogin().execute();

        //Get radio button value
        LoadPreferences();

    } //OnCreate

    private void showNoFavtText(boolean show) {
        noFavtsTV.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); //jika data yang ditampilkan tidak ada, maka show noFavsTv
        recyclerView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //jika data yang ditampilkan tidak ada, maka don't show rV
    }

    private void LoadPreferences(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, null,false);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)contentView.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
        RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
        savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);

        RadioGroup genderGroup = (RadioGroup) contentView.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        RadioButton male = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.theme1);
        RadioButton female = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.theme2);

        if (genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTidur);
            tb.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
        else {
            if (male.isChecked()) {     // one of the radio buttons is checked
                Toolbar tb1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTidur);
                tb1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            }
            else if (female.isChecked()) {
                Toolbar tb2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTidur);
                tb2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }
        }
    }


    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(ChildTidur.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        java.net.URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            showNoFavtText(false);
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tMencoba terhubung ke internet...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("https://api.kafeinkode.com/childtidur.json");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {
                    return("koneksi gagal");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }

        }

        /**
         * fetches json by making http calls
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    pdLoading.dismiss();

                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        // Parsing json
                        List<Story> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Story>>() {

                        }.getType());
                        // adding contacts to contacts list
                        storyList.clear();
                        storyList.addAll(items);
                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        for (int i=0; i<storyList.size(); i++) {
                            Story story = new Story();
                            story.setIdStory(String.valueOf(i));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pdLoading.dismiss();
                    // error in getting json
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak bisa menampilkan data. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChildTidur.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Data Tidak bisa ditampilkan. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    showNoFavtText(true);
                }
            });

            TidurSearch.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_tidur, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable_tidur configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search2).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search2) {
            return true;
        }

        //Menu
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        else
        if (id == R.id.about_us) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutUs.class));
            return true;
        }
        else
        if (id == R.id.favlist) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowFavouriteList.class));
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // close search view on back button pressed
        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void whiteNotificationBar(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(Story story) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected: " + story.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**TidurAdapter.java**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Another problem lays here when I get id of data
                    Story story = storyList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    int ambilId = Integer.parseInt(story.getIdStory());

                    if ( 0 == ambilId ) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaMauTidur.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                    else if ( 1 == getAdapterPosition() )
                    {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaBangunt.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                    else if ( 2 == getAdapterPosition() )
                    {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaJimak.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                }
```

This is a full code:

**Story.java**

```
    public Story(){}

    String name;
    String nomor;
    private String idStory;
    private int isLiked;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getNomor() { return nomor; }

    public void setIdStory(String isStory) {
        this.idStory = isStory;
    }
    public String getIdStory() {
        return idStory;
    }

    public void setIsLiked(int isLiked) {
        this.isLiked = isLiked;
    }
    public int getIsLiked() {
        return isLiked;
    }

}
```

**ChildTidur.java**

```
 /**
         * fetches json by making http calls
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    pdLoading.dismiss();

                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        // Parsing json
                        List<Story> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Story>>() {

                        }.getType());
                        // adding contacts to contacts list
                        storyList.clear();
                        storyList.addAll(items);
                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        for (int i=0; i<storyList.size(); i++) {
                            Story story = new Story();
                            story.setIdStory(String.valueOf(i));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pdLoading.dismiss();
                    // error in getting json
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak bisa menampilkan data. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChildTidur.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Data Tidak bisa ditampilkan. Periksa kembali sambungan internet Anda");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    showNoFavtText(true);
                }
            });

            TidurSearch.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }
    }
```

**TidurAdapter.java**

```
public class TidurAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TidurAdapter.TidurViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private List<Story> storyList;
    private List<Story> storyListFiltered;
    private ContactsAdapterListener listener;

    private int changedItemPosition;
    public boolean isLiked;
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;
    Boolean checked = false;

    public TidurAdapter(Context context, List<Story> storyList, ContactsAdapterListener listener, AppPreferences appPreferences) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.storyList = storyList;
        this.storyListFiltered = storyList;
        this.appPreferences = appPreferences;
    }

    @Override
    public TidurViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_row_item_tidur, parent, false);
        return new TidurViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TidurViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Story story = storyListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(story.getName());
        holder.nomor.setText(story.getNomor());
        holder.setViewData(storyList.get(position), holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return storyListFiltered.size();
    }


    public interface ContactsAdapterListener {
        void onContactSelected(Story story);
    }

    //ViewHolder
    public class TidurViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name;
        public TextView nomor;
        public ImageView mFavorite;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;
        final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";

        public TidurViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            nomor = view.findViewById(R.id.nomor);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // get id of data
                    Story story = storyList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    int ambilId = Integer.parseInt(story.getIdStory());

                    if ( 0 == ambilId ) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaMauTidur.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                    else if ( 1 == getAdapterPosition() )
                    {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaBangunt.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                    else if ( 2 == getAdapterPosition() )
                    {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaJimak.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                }
            });

            //Get radio button value
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View cV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, null,false);
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)cV.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
            RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
            savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);

            RadioGroup genderGroup = (RadioGroup) cV.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
            RadioButton male = (RadioButton) cV.findViewById(R.id.theme1);
            RadioButton female = (RadioButton) cV.findViewById(R.id.theme2);

            if (genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                nomor.setBackgroundColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            } else {
                if (male.isChecked()) {     // one of the radio buttons is checked
                    nomor.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.rounded_drawable));
                }
                else if (female.isChecked()) {
                    nomor.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.rounded_drawable_red));
                }
            }

        } //TidurViewHolder(View view)


        public void setViewData(final Story story, final int adapterPosition) {

            if (story.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            isLiked = true;
                            updateLikes();
                            appPreferences.saveFavouriteCard(story);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            updateLikes();
                            appPreferences.deleteCard(story.getIdStory());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //setviewdata

        public void updateLikes() {
            if (isLiked && storyList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika dilakukan like (pada posisi hati kosong) di halaman home
                storyList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(1); //maka jadikan hati berwarna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemChanged(changedItemPosition, ACTION_LIKE_IMAGE_CLICKED);
            }
            else if (!isLiked && storyList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 1) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman home
                storyList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemChanged(changedItemPosition, ACTION_LIKE_IMAGE_CLICKED);
            }

        } //updateLikes

    }//Class TidurViewHolder

}
```

The error result is, it is showing null... Which mean no ID that can be obtained.

Comment: As I can see your JSON does not have idStory in its result. Is that ID that you want in your gson result?

Comment: Yes, I wanna set an ID for each data, and then I wanna get an ID for each data. I was do `setIdStory()`, and I've tried to get the ID with `getIdStory()`, but it doesn't work. Help me please,, I've been stuck many days here...

Comment: In your story.setIdStory(String.valueOf(i)) you do not get any value because your json response from this url https://api.kafeinkode.com/childtidur.json does not have any idStory. Put a breakpoint at line List<Story> items and check if list has any values.

Comment: Breakpoint? What it mean? 

Yes. In that url, there is no iD. Because of this I want a set an iD based on `storyList.size();`. But it remain fail...

Comment: In your for loop instead of Story story = new Story();                          story.setIdStory(String.valueOf(i)); use this "storyList.get(i).setIdStory(String.valueOf(i));"

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: So you did not serialize any data for your List. This mean that your items list is empty and so storyList. Try to use @SerializedName("name") String name; @SerializedName("nomor") String nomor;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you are not setting id of your List, but your new Story.

Instead of:

```
for (int i=0; i<storyList.size(); i++) {
   Story story = new Story();
   story.setIdStory(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Use this:

```
for (int i=0; i<storyList.size(); i++) {
    storyList.get(i).setIdStory(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Also because your index i=0 starts from zero, you should change for loop index i to start from 1 like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=storyList.size(); i++) {
    storyList.get(i).setIdStory(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Check this main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    private ArrayList<Story> storyList;

    // url to fetch contacts json
    private static final String URL = "https://api.kafeinkode.com/childtidur.json";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        storyList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Fetch JSON data
        fetchData();
    }

    private void fetchData(){
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    // Parsing json
                    List<Story> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Story>>() {}.getType());
                    // adding contacts to contacts list
                    storyList.clear();
                    storyList.addAll(items);

                for (int i=0; i<storyList.size(); i++) {
                    storyList.get(i).setIdStory(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                }
                Log.d("StoryLid: ", storyList.toString());
                }    
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error in getting json
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

       VolleyService.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

As a result you have response:

[image: AndroidStudio]

Comment: This is the result when I try to get data with `getIdStory()`:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Comment: So you did not serialize any data for your List. This means that your List<Story> items list is empty and so storyList and gson did not serialize any json data. Try to use @SerializedName("name") String name; @SerializedName("nomor") String nomor; in your Story class and try again.

Comment: Yes I did, I've written that in Story.java. And the result still same. java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Comment: Is your List<Story> items empty? What do you have in your list?

Comment: Sometimes I think about it,, If it really empty, I have no idea what should I write to fill it...

I just have a data from this url: api.kafeinkode.com/childtidur.json

Comment: If it is empty your gson is not serializing json response to your items list correctly.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: In your logcat do you see output of this debug line: 
Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

Comment: I don't see that. The most important result from the logcat is:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null" and at id.or.tauhid.doadandzikir.TidurAdapter$TidurViewHolder$1.onClick(TidurAdapter.java:131)

Comment: Following your code,, Every I try to click every row of item with `getIdStory()` in TidurAdapter.java, it doesn't response anything. I suggest you to do that... I don't know what happen...

Comment: Yes it won't do anything as I have reduce code to show you how to fetch JSON data from your API.

Comment: First, I don't reduce code as you did. I just change a part of code. Second, I want get an ID of every item with `getIdStory()`. Oh my god... please! My need is very understood...

Comment: I am glad that I could help you ;)